# Редактирование файла через командную строку в node js

Tags: node.js, файлы, cmd

Пишу небольшую программу, которая позволяет юзеру через кмд редачить файлы, и надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог вписывать в файл текст построчно (написал строку, нажал enter, строка добавилась в файл, юзер снова пишет строку, и так пока он не напишет что-то вроде stop).
Получилось что-то вроде такого:

```js
rl.question('Запишите строчку в файл', (answer) => {
  fs.appendFileSync(fileName,answer);
  rl.close();
  console.log(fs.readFileSync(fileName,"utf-8")); //Вывод содержимого файла после заполнения строки
});
```

Теперь нужно сделать цикл, в котором снова и снова будет вызываться rl.question(), но сделать это так, чтобы следующая итерация цикла начиналась только после получения ответа от пользователя.
Пробовал await в сочетании с while, не помогло - запускается бесконечный цикл с выведением в командную строку "Запишите строчку в файл" (бесконечный потому что юзер чисто физически не может вписать что-либо)
Буду очень признателен, если кто-то подскажет, как можно получить данные о том, получен ли ответ от пользователя, и как, если ответ отрицательный, запретить следующую итерацию цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основываясь на примере из документации [Tiny CLI](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli) можно написать событийный функционал без циклов и рекурсии, однако оно будет работать как рекурсия
просто предлагая каждый раз ввод, до тех пор пока мы принудительно не закроем интерфейс ввода.

Плюсом данного метода так же является то что использовании стандартных клавиш прерывания ввода в консоли таких как <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> событие `close` так же отработает.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
rl.setPrompt('Запишите строчку в файл>');

const fileName = 'output.txt';

rl.prompt(); // запускаем процесс ввода

rl.on('line', function(answer) {
    if (answer.trim() === 'stop') rl.close() // прерываем
    fs.appendFileSync(fileName, answer); // пишем в файл
    rl.prompt(); // продолжаем процесс ввода
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('файл записан'); // тут можно чистить ресурсы если нужно
    process.exit(0); // завершаем работу скрипта если нужно
});
```

Пример работы, слева файл, справа консоль:

[image: пример работы]

Comment: Содержимое файла никак не изменяется. Путём небольшой проверки я понял, что проблема находится именно в записи, так как значение программа получает (я добавил строчку `console.log(answer)`, и выводилось ровно то, что я вписал в кмд на ввод)

Comment: Не хочеться писать бональшину `у меня все работает`, но я проверял код перед тем как выложить, содержимое менялось только перевода строк нет, я смотрел именно по файлу, так как answer содержит только последний ввод

Comment: Я использую `VS Code` для того чтобы динамически следить за файлом, например `Sublime` так не умеет.

Comment: Странно, но программа работает корректно, только если запускать её через имя файла (до этого я запускал через node <имя папки>, потому что файл назван index.js, всё отображалось корректно, но запись корректно не работала). В любом случае, теперь всё работает, подтверждаю ответ.

Comment: никогда так не запускал скрипты, но попробовал, в этом случае у файл пишется не в папке а на уровне выше т.е. рядом с папкой где скрипт

Comment: Действительно, нашёл output.txt в папке с папкой проекта
Извините, что не углядел

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте свою функцию, которая будет асинхронная.

```js
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });
const fileName = 'test.txt';

(async function ()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const answer = await rl.question('Запишите строчку в файл');

        if (answer === 'stop')
        {
            rl.close();
            break;
        }

        // Если уловную команду "стоп" нужно писать в файл, код ниже перенести выше if
        fs.appendFileSync(fileName, answer);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" в ответ на строку "const { answer } = await asyncQuestion(rl, 'Запишите строчку в файл');".

Comment: Да.. Цикл должен быть в какой-то асинхронной функции.. Хотя я думал, в ноде можно использовать `await` в основном потоке..

Comment: Запихнул цикл в асинхронную функцию примерно таким образом: `async function func(){while (true)
{
    const { answer } = await asyncQuestion(rl, 'Запишите строчку в файл');
    if (answer === 'stop')
    {
        break;
    }
}}
func();`
Результат изменился - ошибки нет, но и rl.question() не срабатывает корректно

Comment: А что не так срабатывает?

Comment: В кмд появляется возможность вписать что-либо для пользователя, но фраза "Запишите строчку в файл" не выводится. Естественно, то, что запишет пользователь, никуда не идёт (редактируемый файл остаётся неизменным)

Comment: А что у вас хранится в `rl`?

Comment: const rl=require("readline");

Comment: Я конечно обновил ответ, но не думаю, что это чем-то поможет.. По сути все должно работать.. Странно.

Comment: Странности продолжаются... Возможно это из-за недопонимания, того что происходит в коде до объявления асинхронной функции asyncQuestion. Высылаю код:
`const fs=require("fs");
const readline = require('node:readline');
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('node:process');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });;
let fileName='test.txt';` Код был взят из официальной документации readline (частично): https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: Я не знаю эту библиотеку.. но по коду я увидел, что callback функцию можно не передавать и тогда метод вернет промис, результат которого и можно дождаться с помощью `await`, я сейчас обновлю ответ, скажите, получится ли что-то.

Comment: Только я не уверен, что нужно делать `rl.close()` после каждого вопроса. Возможно закрытие нужно делать в блоке с проверкой на `stop`.